# Any ideas on why I cant "Load contract from Address" in Remix?

Tags: remix, metamask

- I have compiled the code and the code is the same as the deployed contract

[image: "At Address" is greyed out and I am unable to view the contract]

Any tips would be appreciated, I deployed this contract just yesterday.

Comment: Are you pasting the address without any quotes?

Comment: It is probably a bug in Remix maybe something is cached, have you tried another browser ?